# Stored procedure in SQL Server does not return a result set when called by java

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, resultset

I have the following stored procedure and my goal is to return a result set from it, using the query "select * from #justTmp"

```
create procedure spAddPerson
    @ID int,
    @Name nvarchar(50)
as
begin
    create table #justTmp
    (
        num int primary key,
        justName nvarchar(50)
    )

    if @ID in (select C.ContributorID
               from Contributors C)
    begin
        insert into #justTmp
        values (@ID, @Name)
    end

    select *
    from #justTmp
end
```

And this is my java code

```
CallableStatement cstmt = null; 
ResultSet rs = null;

cstmt=conn.prepareCall("{ call spAddPerson(?,?) }");
cstmt.setInt(1, 1);
cstmt.setString(2, "MyName");

cstmt.execute();
rs=cstmt.getResultSet();
int first=rs.getInt(1);
String second=rs.getString(2);
```

For some reason, whenever I run it, and the above stored procedure is called, I get an exception that says

> The statement did not return a result set

when the

```
rs = cstmt.getResultSet()
```

code is executed.

Any idea how to fix this so a result set would return and not null?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try and add SET NOCOUNT ON at the top of the proc

Comment: @Ian-Fogelman How? Like this?
create proc spAddPerson
SET NOCOUNT ON?

Comment: If you run the stored procedure manually (like in SSMS) with the same `@ID` the Java program uses, do you get a result set?  Also, on the line after `begin` is where to put `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

Comment: @user212514 Yes, I do get result set running it manually in SSMS

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
create proc spAddPerson
    @ID int,
    @Name nvarchar(50)
    as
    begin
SET NOCOUNT ON
    ...
```

Comment: I get "The result set has no current row" while running the java, but if I try to execute the procedure directly in SQL Server it does return result set

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways but try this once:

create proc spAddPerson
    @ID int,
    @Name nvarchar(50)
    as
    begin
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
    create table #justTmp
    (
    num int primary key,
    justName nvarchar(50)
    )


    if @ID  in
    (
      select C.ContributorID
      from Contributors C
    )
    begin
    insert into #justTmp
    values(@ID,@Name)
    end

    select *
    from #justTmp

 RETURN
end
```

Comment: I get the error message "The result set has no current row" running the java.

Answer (score 0):

On your java code change

call spAddPerson

To

exec spAddPerson